# Escaping double quotes in Rails link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to the Rails framework and Ruby language in general but I do have some programming and MVC experience.  I am trying to output a link using rails' link_to method.  However in the HTML this link is inside another set of double quotes.  I need to escape the quotes produced by rails in the  tag.

I have tried google and only found information for javascript escaping which didnt help. I tried using a h(%[]) method that was mentioned a few times but then the link was not created and the actual words link_to were out put.

Does anyone know how I can escape the double quotes in the hyperlink tag created by rails or switch it to use a single quote?

Actual Code

```
<% @properties = Property.all 
                            @properties.each do |property| %>
                            <img src="images/img<%= property.id %>.jpg" alt="" title="<strong><%= property.address %></strong><span>9 rooms, 3 baths, 6 beds, building size: 5000 sq. ft. &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Price: $ 600 000 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <%= link_to "Read More", property) %></span>">
                            <% end %>
```

Output

```
<img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="" title="<strong>50 Craft LAne</strong><span>9 rooms, 3 baths, 6 beds, building size: 5000 sq. ft. &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Price: $ 600 000 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="/properties/1">Read More</a></span>">
```

The first double quote in the hyperlink is pairing with the title=" and then everything is off

Comment: Please show the actual code you are trying.  It'll help you get more answers.

Comment: Edited the original post to include code and output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
<%= link_to("Read More", property).gsub("\"", "'") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

link_to '"something"'

Does not work? Give an example of what you whant